# Issue with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio-2.0

[I have an issue when trying to download the system image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuvAW.png)

I opened the virtual device configuration to create a virtual device after that I found the device without the Google Play Store.

Any help would be appreciated cause I am trying to solve the problem and still can't find the solution